# Проблема с рукописным текстом CSS

Tags: css, шрифты

**При комбинации свойств для текста:**

```
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: cursive;
```

**Русская буква т начитает залезать на другие.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как можно решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zhihar верно отметил, что помочь может свойство letter-spacing. Вот только если задать его для всего текста, то получится не очень красиво. Поэтому предлагаю обернуть буквы `т` в `span`и уже отдельно для спана увеличить межбуквенный интервал:

```css
body {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: cursive;
}
span {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
Мес<span>т</span>о вс<span>т</span>речи измени<span>т</span>ь нельзя
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте поиграться расстоянием между буквами через свойство `letter-spacing`

```
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: cursive;
letter-spacing: 5px;
```